# при отправке http запроса в c# программа залагивает

Tags: c#, http

при отправке запроса http программа на 1-2 с  зависает . помогите решить эту проблему

```
WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?owner_id=12&message=" + textBox1.Text + "&access_token=af166ff4349108e2d713");
request.Proxy = new WebProxy("89.36.210.59", 3128);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);    
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
dynamic json = JObject.Parse(responseFromServer);
var status = json.response.post_id;
```

Comment: без кода ответить смогут только шаманы. добавляйте код в вопрос, нам нужен минимальный пример, воспроизводящий проблему. да и помимо кода может быть что угодно на компе из программ стоять: убедитесь, что программа воспроизводится и на других машинах.

Comment: В этом коде нечему виснуть на 1 - 2 секунды, мы можем смело закрывать этот вопрос как "не воспроизводится" и давать рецепты общего вида, как-то: "уверены ли вы, что хотите через быструю прокси, попробуйте другие или вообще без", "возможно, сегодня тормозил один из серверов ВК" или даже (бывает и такое) "отключите свой антивирус".

Comment: Необходимо вынести запрос в отдельный поток и сделать через асинхронные операции. Тогда зависания не будет, даже если запрос долго обрабатывается. Вообще все такого рода "длинные по времени" запросы и операции желательно делать в отдельных потоках. И в случае потока UI обязательно делать в отдельных потоках.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин поясните пжста, в чем смысл выполнения асинхронного запроса в отдельном потоке? Почему его нельзя вызвать с UI потока?

Comment: @tym32167 Потому если действие делается в UI потоке и по времени занимает 2 секунды, значит весь UI поток зависает на 2 секунды. А если 10 секунд, то 10. В примере выше действие синхронно а не асинхронно.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин асинхронный запрос не задерживает UI поток, время на создание самого запроса исчисляется микросекундами, потому мне интересно в каких случаях затраты на создание нового потока или постановку задачи в пул потоков могут оправдать создание асинхронного запроса в отдельном потоке?

Comment: Может быть я не правильно выразился, я имел ввиду что для данной операции нужен отдельный поток.

Comment: @tym32167 да, согласен, но в примере выше не вижу await -ов или taskoв.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин да, я потому и уточняю, что автор создал второй вопрос, где уже просит запустить этот код в отдельном потоке, хотя имхо тут больше подходит асинхронность, что я там и посоветовал, чем привлек внимание модератора :)

Comment: Но ведь асинхронная операция уже делается в отдельном потоке.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин нет, асинхронная операция - это не многопоточная операция. Преимущество асинхронности как раз в том, что она не занимает поток. То есть, когда вы ждете БД или ждете сетевого ответа в синхронном варианте ваш поток ожидает и не может быть использован другим кодом. В асинхронном варианте ваш поток не ждет завершения операции. Потому UI и не виснет, когда выполняется асинхронная операция.

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо. Да, понял, у меня тут было неправильное понимание, разбираюсь с этой темой.